# Request failed: client error (422) QuicBlox

Tags: ios, chat, voip, quickblox

We implemented QuickBlox chat and voip, it was working fine.
Two days back suddenly got error while sending voip pushnotifications.

Please see the below error message:

Send voip push - Error

```
    Optional(Error Domain=xxxxx.quickblox.com Code=422 "Request failed: client error (422)" 
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxx.quickblox.com/events.json, NSLocalizedFailureReason={
    errors = (
    "No one can receive the message"
    );
    }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: client error (422)})
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working ?

Comment: It worked later, I am not remembering the fix. Also, not recommending QuickBlox their developer support is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a subscription does not exist for this device, you can check it in admin panel. Here is an [article](https://quickblox.com/developers/Messages#Create_subscription_.28subscribes.29) about creating subscriptions.

Comment: NO, I have checked that. Subscriptions was there .

Answer (score 0):

Got this working.... We have to connect to chat to establish the session and then perform call

First call this API and the session would be established

```
QBChat.instance.connect
```

and then perform the call action.

[Documentation](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/ios-video-calling)